# mvc ajax refresh div method controller json

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in the controller that return a ViewBag with Json.

```
 public JsonResult FilterCheck(int id, int[] mycheck, string idprot)
    {
    ViewBag.Utenti = this.GetDbContext().utente.Include(s => s.cod_servizio_utente).Where(x => x.cod_servizio_utente.Select(l => l.id).Contains(5)).ToList();

return Json(ViewBag.Utenti, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

In the view I have this script function ajax, if this function have "success" i would refresh a div that include a foreach on the viebag.Utenti:

```
 $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("FilterCheck","Operatore")",
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: { 'mycheck': mycheck, 'idprot': idprot, 'id': '@Model.id' },
                success: function(data) {
                    var html = $(data).filter('#external-events').html();
                    $('#external-events').html(data);
                }
            });

<div id='external-events'>

              @foreach (HAnnoZero.Repositories.utente item in ViewBag.Utenti)
        {
            <div class='col-lg-3'><div class='external-event'>@item.id- @item.cognome @item.nome</div></div>    
        }    </div>
```

But dont work. How can do for refresh the foreach inside div id "external events"?Who could help me?

Comment: show the json reponse and question is not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: Hello Ehsan, I am trying to refresh the @foreach item in the viewBag.Utenti inside the div id=external events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you do not need to assign the collection to ViewBag

```
public ActionResult FilterCheck(int id, int[] mycheck, string idprot)
{
  var data = this.GetDbContext().utente.Include(......
  // Build anonymous object collection to avoid circular reference errors
  var response = data.Select(d => new
  {
    id = d.id,
    cognome = d.cognome
    // other properties as required
  });
  return Json(response);
}
```

Secondly you are returning JSON, not html, so in your success function you need to iterate through the properties and build your html (not sure what your properties are, so adjust as necessary)

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#external-events').empty(); // clear existing items
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    var div = $('<div><div>'); // Create new element
    div.text(item.id + ' ' + item.cognome); // Set inner text
    $('#external-events').append(div); // add the new element
  });
}
```

An alternative is to have the action method return a partial view containing the html and then use

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#external-events').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen...but doesn't work the console say ERROR 500 internal server error

Comment: Put a breakpoint on you controller and see where the error is.

Comment: The strange thing is that in the controller i dont have some error. The var data work fine..but in the success(ajax) do not enter

Comment: In the first line of the success function add `console.log(data);` to check what is being returned.

Comment: I have put console.log(data) in the first line of the error because in the success dont enter. The console give back this:Circular reference detected while serializing an object of type 'HAnnoZero.Repositories.utente'

Comment: If the success function is not hit, then there is an on the server. To test, replace `return Json(data);` with `return Json("This is a test");` and check the output.

Comment: error comes from ViewBag.Utenti = this.GetDbContext().utente.Include(s => s.cod_servizio_utente).Where(x => x.cod_servizio_utente.Select(l => l.id).Contains(5)).ToList(); step. circular reference error

Comment: @AlessioDeCastro, You need to change your query or (better) create an anonymous object that includes only the properties you need to return to the view - e.g. `var response = data.Select(d => new { id = d.id, cognome = d.cognome, etc }); return Json(response);`

Comment: Stephen's answer is good (I voted up for the suggestion of using Json), typically you can return Json with a serializer, which avoids your select statement, example usage...               **`return Json(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DotNetDataObjectHere));`**                                 this utilizes the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` and requires a `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` statement. Hope this helps make life easier (less error prone).